# Deal with running service (in sdk) in several apps use same sdk on one device

Tags: android, android-service

Im making advertisement sdk for android with running background service.
Imagine, 3 apps on one device have integrated my sdk. All 3 apps are active. They have different package name and start 3 same service from sdk.

Server can make deduplication user by android id and google aid.

How to make service singleton cross other apps?

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't really understand your question... What do you mean 'deal with client'?

Comment: edited, pls check

Comment: I haven't tried it but you can try to use a ordered broadcast receiver to receive broadcast to start the service. Then when the first receiver gets the call it calls `abortBroadcast` which should stop from sending it the other receivers.

Comment: i don't understand your point, how could server duplicate user? i think when your client registers with your ad, they should get an ID which is unique that need to be used in the service. --- i don't think you can make the service singleton cross other apps, that's not correct, if this is the case you need to have the sdk-service running as a separate app, that handle other apps request, (like google services) , you can't use it from within an app to serve other apps, what if that app got killed, crashed, closed, uninstalled, what will other  2 apps do ?

Comment: Yazan, thank you. Yes, we have unique user id cross all apps on device. I can not make separate app :( I need it work as sdk in apps. I think other service need to watch to "master" service ,or server has to say who is master.